# A better way to implement event ticketing system database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm adding a ticketing feature on a site where user can advertise their events. I want to add a ticketing feature where user can create a ticket for an event and then users can purchase those tickets. I came up with following database structure( it's not very neat but I hope it explains what i'm trying to do). so my question is this the correct way to do? or am I going to have problem with this in future?[image: ticketing system]

Comment: There's not really enough information to determine that. Most things look alright, but i'm not sure what the difference for the different event_(type|id) relations is; in `booked_tickets` using `email` as foreign key would be a bad idea (even for guests), that should probably be replaced by 2 synthetic id fields; its not really clear how you picture the tickets.`qty` thing working out (or if/how you plan to enforce that); thats just a couple things that come to mind

Comment: There's always more than one solution to this sort of problem, and which is best can change as the system grows. This seems OK for now. Will it handle the load in five year's time? Who can say?

Comment: thank you for the reply @Raxi. there are different database tables for different event types(ik that doesn't make sense it is the way the previous developer designed it so cant change that). so first i have to look which type of event that is and then i look for the table associated with that to take its id as ref. and i'm not taking email as a ref. it's just that the diagram is not accurate with the standards. and for the qty it will be decided by the one creates tickets. will reduce the amount after each purchase.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I guess you're right. I should just implement as it is for now and then wait for something to break to improve it.

Comment: Generally speaking you're a lot better off having 1 id field for each possible eventdetailtable than having 1 id that can refer to multiple tables. All the irrelevant ones can be null; and you can add a constraint to the table that /only/ one of them may have a value (or w/e special combination you decide).

Answer (score 0):

**about implemention**

Read some about design patterns specially [observer design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/php/example) for your case:

as it is written for the [purpose](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Behavioral/Observer/README.html) of observer design pattern:

> To implement a publish/subscribe behavior to an object, whenever a “Subject” object changes its state, the attached “Observers” will be notified. It is used to shorten the amount of coupled objects and uses loose coupling instead.

after implementation of such design pattern as mentioned, you can simply notify all entities and their corresponding controllers to do your desired action just like :

- send a notification when an event expires
- when an event changes its state and u want to do some actions based on this change.
- whatever else that needs a supervised action

also if your events have the same creation procedure but with different supplies, you can use a [builder design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder/php/example) for creating them.

for example:
you all events you are creating needs register information, needs notify users, needs triggered logs, needs ...
you can use this pattern for creating events.

there are probably other design patterns that can be fit on your project but you must extract them based on other requirements that u don't mention in question.

**about your ERD:**

the `purchased ticket` table must be a pivot table, so UID can be settled in this table (not  `ticket`), information about payments (`paied_price`, `transaction_id`, ...) can be in another table with all payments information (say  `payments`), and users information remains in `user` table (information like email.)

but anyway this is my suggestion, absolutely you can normalize your data model with other systems' data to what level you want and create your normalized tables.

Comment: thank you @behzad for the reply. I need uid in ticket so i can get the user/organiser who created the ticket. The design patterns you suggested are interesting and i would love to learn them but implementing them in the current system will be pain since it doesnt use any framework or pattern of any kind.